# Google Map v2 ImageView remains invisible even if set as visible

Tags: android, imageview

I need to show and hide an ImageView based on the user's behavior.  I set the ImageView to be invisible in `onCreate()` and I try to make it visible again when the user selects an item in the OptionsMenu.  The Strange thing is it doesn't show up at all and will only show up after the Activity resumes.

Here is the XML code:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/rectimage"
    android:layout_width="20dp"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:src="@drawable/rect" />
```

Where I hide imageview

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.rectimage);
    image.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}
```

Where I try to make it visible again

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {              
    case R.id.menu_visible:
        image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);          
    return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Here is onStart and onResume , not do anything.

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    Log.w(TAG, "-- ON Start --");

}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Log.w(TAG, "-- ON Resume --");
}
```

And here is my drawable resource in XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  android:shape="rectangle">
<solid android:color="@android:color/transparent"/>
<corners android:radius="20px"/> 
<stroke  android:width="2dip" android:color="#000000"/>  
</shape>
```

Comment: Post the code where you hide and show the ImageView too.

Comment: Can you post onResume()?

Comment: @gatnowurry I have post it too

Comment: @ShawnLien I found nothing wrong in your code. Please check logcat if there is an error saying `requesting window feature should be done before super.onCreate()`

Comment: @Pragnani It never return any error

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are drawing a transparent rectangle:

```
<solid android:color="@android:color/transparent"/>
```

Are you seeing the border being drawn?

Also, did you try putting a break point in `onOptionsItemSelected` to make sure it is being called?

Comment: I am prettry sure this is not the problem.  transparent only make my image have hollow in the middle. It still will show the line

Comment: ImageView only draws what you tell it to. The only thing you are telling it to draw is a transparent rectangle. There is no background being set on it, so the only thing it knows about is the `src` you set.

Comment: @ChristopherPerry But If I press home button and leave the app.  After Resume the image will show up.  And if I remove this tranparent from the XML it still have same problem.

Comment: @ChristopherPerry But it is a drawable resource, so it will be show up no matter whether it is transparent or not, because it has corners, I have pasted above drawable selector and I am able see image on my emulator

Comment: @Pragnani I think I might know the reason.  In my whole code the imageView is actully place on other view.  So after I make it invisible when create it will keep invisible even after make it visible. Because it get cover by other view, and only will appear once activity get create again.  Am I right?